# Revoke multiple client certs signed by one CA: only the first one got denied?

Tags: openvpn, openssl, crl

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04
- OpenVPN version: 2.2.1-8
- Setup: one CA cert, one server cert, multiple client certs

Server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/team.log
syslog vpn-team
verb 4
writepid /var/run/openvpn-team.pid
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/team/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/team/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
server 172.16.255.128 255.255.255.128
ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/team/ipp.txt
client-to-client
push "route 172.16.0.0 255.255.254.0"
crl-verify crl.pem
```

client config:

```
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 4
client
remote x.x.x.x 1194
ca ca.crt
cert team.crt
key team.key
remote-cert-tls server
```

Using `revoke-full` script from `easy-rsa` package, I saw that it only output the last one into a `crl.pem` file:

```
# generate a new CRL -- try to be compatible with
# intermediate PKIs
$OPENSSL ca -gencrl -out "$CRL" -config "$KEY_CONFIG"
```

In my case, I wrote a script to append to that file but only the first one got denied, all other one can still connect.

Using `openssl crl`, it just show the serial of the first one:

```
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: E9955907C7F48BDDFCADCFECFAEDC8B7
        Revocation Date: Feb 11 08:57:19 2015 GMT
```

So, the question is: does `crl-verify` support a concatenated CRL file? Is it a limit of openssl?

Related:

- http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2007-02/msg00191.html
- http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-devel/2005-05/msg00018.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openvpn-users/g2GdaotzB5Q

Answer (score 0):

> So, the question is: does `crl-verify` support a concatenated CRL file?

No. The `crl.pem` is just something like this:

```
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----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-----END X509 CRL-----
```

but using `openssl crl -in /path/to/crl.pem -text -noout`, if multiple certs has been revoked, you will see something like this:

```
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: 01
        Revocation Date: Feb 13 14:59:08 2015 GMT
    Serial Number: 02
        Revocation Date: Feb 13 14:59:10 2015 GMT
```

> I wrote a script to append to that file but only the first one got denied, all other one can still connect.

I was wrong at this step. Read the `revoke-full` script carefully:

```
# revoke key and generate a new CRL
$OPENSSL ca -revoke "$1.crt" -config "$KEY_CONFIG"

# generate a new CRL -- try to be compatible with
# intermediate PKIs
$OPENSSL ca -gencrl -out "$CRL" -config "$KEY_CONFIG"
```

OpenSSL has an `index.txt` file where it keep all cert info:

- status: (V)alid, (E)xpired, (R)evoked
- expiry date
- revocation date
- serial number
- file name of the cert (unknown)
- subject

The first command (`openssl ca -revoke`) actually update that `index.txt` file to replace V (valid) with R (revoke).
The second command (`openssl ca -gencrl`) create a `crl.pem` file based on `index.txt` and CA cert/key.

So, don't append to the existing `crl.pem` file, just update the `index.txt` first, then re-generate CRL.

Comment: The pem file can not be concatenated yet contains multiple certs.  CRL stands for Cert Revocation List.  View the certs in the file with the following command.
sudo openssl crl -inform PEM -in /path/to/crl.pem -text -noout